# cmake cannot read some of my environments variables

Tags: cmake, environment-variables

I have a cmake script that tries to resolve a path by reading an environment variable. When running that script (I print out the value of the environment variable), the message is empty (meaning the env var wasn't read successfully). However for other env vars (like `PATH`, `CUDA_PATH`, `WINDIR`, ...), this works. But some (like `OpenCV_DIR`, `GOROOT`, `VCPKG_ROOT`, ...) simply don't resolve. They are all machine wide environment variables.

The line that print the env var is

```
message("ENV VAR: " $ENV{SOME_VAR})
```

Why are some env vars resolved correctly while others aren't?

**Edit**: I'm on Windows 10 using cmake 3.11.1

**Edit2**: To clarify some things: cmake is invoked from vcpkg package manager and all environment variables are system wide and persistent (verified; they were set at some point in the past and *setting* those vars is not part of the build process).

Comment: Are you sure they're all environment variables?  Your example patterns that don't work look like cmake variables, not environment variables.

Comment: They are all env vars 100%. I can print them all in powershell with `echo $env:SOME_VAR`

Comment: Please, show how do you set those environment variables, which are not reflected in CMake.

Comment: @Tsyvarev what do you mean with *how do you set those*? Those are persistant environment variables that were set at some point in the past. Not during the build process or sth.

Comment: By "persistent" you mean that variables are set by some startup script, aren't you? Please, provide more info: OS you use, way of CMake invocation, and so on. Currently your question looks like: "I am sure I do things right, and I don't show how. Where is my problem?"

Comment: @Tsyvarev By persistent I mean they were setup on the system at some point in the past. This could be 2 days or 2 years ago and they were set either by hand or by some script. But this is really irrelevant here as setting those env vars is not part of the cmake or any other involved build script.

Comment: Do you run CMake via GUI? If so, GUI process may differ from one which calls it, and which have variables being set.

Comment: @Tsyvarev No I do not use the GUI. Cmake is invoked from vcpkg package manager. But as those vars are system wide env vars, shouldn't each process automatically inherit them on creation?

Comment: `But as those vars are system wide env vars, shouldn't each process automatically inherit them on creation?` - It should, but only if the variables are actually system-wide. E.g., if stored into Windows registry. Unfortunately, I am not an expert in system-wide setting of variables on Windows. However, in your last comment you have provided those details which I have asked before. Please, **add them into the question post** instead, so someone else would help you after reading the question post only, without comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vcpkg, in order to improve robustness and avoid machine contamination, builds are executed in a special "clean" environment. You can get a virtualenv into this environment via the command `vcpkg env --triplet <target triplet>`.

If you want to explicitly enable certain environment variables in the clean environment, you can set them in the triplet file (`triplets\foo.cmake`).

There may also be a better way to achieve what you're looking for (open an issue on the GitHub page).